django-angular Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy
When trying to commit a POST request to the django server I get the following error:
Obj:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/' from origin
'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field
content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

This is the code where I make the request:
return this.http.post(url, data, 
    {headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    })}
)

And this is my django settup for corsheaders:
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = ["access-control-allow-origin"]

Any insight on the problem and how to improve the question will be thanked

Drop that Access-Control-Allow-Headers header from your request and change to CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = ["Accept", "Content-Type"] in your CORS configuration.

@jub0bs, that solved it. What did the access-control-allow-origin header do anyway?

Glad to hear it. Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a CORS response header that is already set by your CORS middleware in the nominal case; there's no good reason to ever list it as an allowed request-header name in your CORS configuration. Recommended reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

@jub0bs, consider posting your answer and your Access-Control-Allow-Headers explanation with the docs as an actual Answer so I can accept it and it can be useful for other people in my situation. Thanks a lot.

As @jub0bs pointed out the problem was solved by:
Dropping the Access-Control-Allow-Headers header from the request and changing it to CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = ["Accept", "Content-Type"] in the CORS configuration.
The Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a CORS response header that is already set by CORS middleware in the nominal case; there's no good reason to ever list it as an allowed request-header name in the CORS configuration.
Recommended reading: developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
